# Can't run C++ app from linux console - "not found" error

Tags: linux, unix, console, console-application

I have 2 MIPS routers running openwrt linux. On one of them things are fine and I can easily run my app from console.
I copy it over scp (this is my app, one file) to another router and when I try to run it, I get "not found" error:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# pwd
/root
root@OpenWrt:~# ls -l
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root        132001 Apr  2 17:37 app
root@OpenWrt:~# ./app
ash: ./app: not found
root@OpenWrt:~# uname -a
Linux OpenWrt 3.7.9 #3 Mon Aug 5 16:25:53 EEST 2013 mips GNU/Linux
```

I'm not a newbie in linux, but can't find what the problem is here.

Comment: I'm not sure but something tells me that this has to do with missing dependencies. Maybe the linker can't find a given dependency that's present on router 1 but not on router 2. Try re-compiling the binary on the target platform.

Comment: can you run  "file ./app"  to check if its actually an executable

Comment: @jDo Maybe depenencies are missing. That is surely possible. But I didn't expect no get "Not found" error here. I don't have ldd on the target platform, so I don't know how to check what dependencies are missing. Do you have any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: @user6170930 it is an executable. I can run it successfully on another router, same architecture

Comment: @rightaway717 Yeah, it's an odd error - not very informative. I've seen something similar when moving compiled binaries around on various systems though.

Comment: @rightaway717 can you run ldd ./app on it?

Comment: @rightaway717 Just found [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18079/159478) that seems to re-produce/demonstrate the error

Comment: @jDo ok, this seems to be the case. thank you. Please post an answer, so I could accept it when confirmed

Comment: @rightaway717 Will do. Hope it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly no compiler expert but from bitter experience when moving binaries around on embedded systems, this cryptic error leads me to believe that it's some sort of dependency error; likely a missing linker. Recompiling the binary on the target system has solved the issue for me in the past.

As Kevin Vasko asked in the comments: *"can you run ldd ./app on it?"*

This is a good way of determining which libraries and linker the program expects. One can also do as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/why-does-sh-say-not-found-when-its-definitely-there/18079#18079) that demonstrates a similar issue and run the following command to get only the "program interpreter" line (`ldd` will show several dependencies):

`readelf -l app | grep "program interpreter"`

On my system, this shows the GNU linker, `ld`, but with an explanatory line of text that might be helpful `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`.

Thus, I suspect that if I removed this "program interpreter" from my system, I would get the same error (and probably quite a few others). Again, try recompiling the binary on the target system or satisfy any missing dependencies manually by moving the right files into the right places.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't have ldd or readelf on target system , but I have them on the working router, so I checked the dependencies there, copied missing ones to the target router and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your ./app I have a feeling you are calling something doesn't exist. In this case the "ash" command.

Based on this error

```
ash: ./app: not found
```

I feel you are running a piece of code inside of your ./app. Based on the "ash" I would say you are trying to run "bash". If I had to guess you mistyped your header in your script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: no, sorry, this is a c++ app actually. no shell here

Comment: @rightaway717 Ah, well is your doing anything with the "ash" shell?

Comment: no, nothing except that I try to run the app in it. I also tried to run it from plain `sh`